# overcome non utf8 url encoding

Tags: php, utf-8, slim, url-encoding

I'm using slim framework, and recently my log shows that I'm getting many uri requests which are not encoded as utf-8.
the text is expected to be in Hebrew, but the value is decoded to some kind of gibberish.

for example I found the following missing uri in the log:
`/product/%c3%97%c2%a0%c3%97%e2%80%a2%c3%97%c2%a8%c3%97%e2%80%9d_%c3%97%c5%93%c3%97%c5%be%c3%97%c2%a7%c3%97%c2%a8%c3%97%c2%a8_120V_40W`

which is decoded to 
`/product/× ×•×¨×”_×œ×ž×§×¨×¨_120V_40W`
while I'm expecting `/product/נורה_למקרר_120V_40W`

I'm not sure who is requesting this uri since I couldn't get niter referrer nor user-agent.
however I can add more variables to the log if needed, just couldn't think about something informative in that case.

Thanks,
Meir

Comment: I found this site: [link](http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en)
which helped me figuring out it's a 'Windows-1254' encoding.
I tried use `$name = iconv("windows-1254" , "UTF-8//IGNORE" , $name)`
and  `mb_convert_encoding($name, 'UTF-8','Windows-1254')`
but it's still gibberish

Comment: Update 2:
Using `mb_convert_encoding($name, 'Windows-1254','UTF-8')`
I'm now getting `נורה_ל�?קרר_120V_40W`
which is a bit similar to the expected text, but still something is missing.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:
`$name = mb_convert_encoding($name, 'Windows-1252','UTF-8');`